# Writing a CSV File with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I did a python script to access a site, and on that site do a certain search for me to do a scan of the search result.

I write the return of the result as `txt`

```
clear = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Whitebackground')
for scrape in clear:
    with open('result.txt', 'a') as writer:
         writer.write(scrape.text)
         writer.write('\n')
         writer.close()
```

I want to return the result in CSV to open in Excel

```
clear = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Whitebackground')
    for scrape in clear:
        with open('result.csv', 'a') as writer:
             writer.write(scrape.text)
             writer.write('\n')
             writer.close()
```

My problem is that I have to fill 4 columns

I get my current result that way

```
656473930362736
The car needs to change the oil
Model: sedan
type of fuel: Gasoline
```

I want to receive my result in CSV in this way

```
'Number'; 'description'; 'Model'; 'Type of fuel'
6564...; The car needs..; sedan ; Gasoline
```

`'Number'`, `'description'`, `'Model'`, '`Type of fuel'` would be the titles by columns

`'6564...'`, `'The car needs...'`, `'sedan'`, `'Gasoline'` Would be the rows of the columns

[image: Excel]

does anyone have any idea how I can do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can convert your data into dictionaries, its super easy:

```
data = []
datapoint = {}
datapoint['Number'] = 656473930362736
datapoint['Description'] = "The car needs to change the oil."
datapoint['Model'] = "Sedan"
datapoint['Type of Fuel'] = "Gasoline"
data.append(datapoint)

fieldnames = ['Number','Description','Model','Type of Fuel']

def filewriter(filename, data, fieldnames):
        with open (filename, "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
                csvfile = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', dialect='excel')
                csvfile.writeheader()
                for row in data:
                        csvfile.writerow(row)

filewriter("out.csv", data, fieldnames)
```

converting your data into dictionaries is a separate problem, but should be no big deal if your data is structured well.

Comment: i get random values ​​to write so i can't do EX: ['Number'] = 656473930362736
the same goes for others.

Comment: so here ['Number'] = scrap

to receive the values ​​he finds on the site

Comment: like I said - how to get the data into a dictionary format is a different problem, which probably can be solved with simple regex - but I cannot say for sure without having seen some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse your text by splitting into elements:

```
txt = "656473930362736\n" \
       "The car needs to change the oil\n" \
       "Model: sedan\n" \
       "type of fuel: Gasoline"

list_of_elements = txt.split('\n')
required_text = list_of_elements[0] + ';' + list_of_elements[1] + ';' list_of_elements[2].split(':')[1] + ';' + list_of_elements[3].split(':') + ';'
file.write(required_text + '\n')
```